# Pagination and listing in APIs

Tags: postgresql, api, solr, pagination, full-text-search

I wanna ask you about lists and pagination in APIs

I want to build a long list in home screen that's mean this request will have a lot of traffic because it's the main screen and I want to build it in a good way to handle the traffic

After I searched about the way of how I gonna implement it

Can I depend on postgresql in pagination ? Or I need to use search engine like solr

If I depend on the database and users started to visit the app, then this request gonna submit a lot of queries on the database is this gonna kill the database ?

Also I'm using Redis to Cache Some data and this gonna handle some traffic but the problem with home screen the response it too large and I can't cache all of this response in one key in Redis

Can anyone explain to me what is the best way to implement this request for pagination .. the only thing I want is pagination I'm not looking to implement a full text search but to handle the traffic I read that search engine will handle it to not affect the database or kill it

Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this seamlessly with the pagination technology we know in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL has enough functions and capabilities to do this. (limit, offset, fetch)

But let me give you a recommendation.

There are several types of pagination.

The first type is that the count of pages must be known in advance. This technology is outdated and is not recommended. Because at this time you need to know the count of records in the table. But calculating count of records is a very slowing process, mainly in large tables.

The second type is that the number of pages is not known in advance. Information from the next page is brought in parts only if necessary. Just like Google, LinkedIn and other big companies use it. In this case, it is not necessary to calculate the count of any table.